# Content-Type value is unexpectedly changed by Jetty9

Tags: jetty

I'm in  trouble about the "Content-Type" .

I used a recent version Jetty, that version is 8.1.11.v20130520.
Now, I'm trying to migrate my application to version 9.0.4.v20130625.

In version 8, Content-Type value is not changed by Jetty.

> **set by client :**
>       application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>
> **HttpServletRequest.getHeade("Content-Type") :**
>       application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8

But in version 9.0.4.v20130625,  "Content-Type" value is changed by Jetty.

> **set by client :**
>       application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
>
> **HttpServletRequest.getHeade("Content-Type") :**
>       application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=***UTF***-8

A charset value is changed(utf -> UTF).

I use this value to calculate a hash value for authentication mechanism.
This changing of a Content-Type value makes difference between a value calculated in client and that in server, so authentication is failed.

Have anybody tips or options to avoid this charset changing?

Comment: I see you ended up filing a bug report for this. Can you please link to it?